# how to read file and skip some white spaces

Tags: f#

this is similiar to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583636/need-help-to-read-file-with-specific-formatted-contents) question,

but there is another improvisation, how is the code if i want to skip some white spaces, for this case is "enter", for example:

```
5 5 10
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
               <- this white space
3 4 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

i try to my best but couldn't find how to skip the white space
thank you for the help :)

This is the answer, thanks to Ramon :

```
let readMap (path:string) =
    let lines = File.ReadAllLines path
    let [|x; y; n|] = lines.[0].Split() |> Array.map int
    let data = 
        [| 
            for l in (lines |> Array.toSeq |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.filter(System.String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not)) do
                yield l.Split()
        |]
    x,y,n,data
```

Comment: White space line is a mark used to separate records or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to write your `readMap` function is to use `if` expression inside the list comprehension. I think this is actually more readable if you're using comprehensions (because you don't have to combine two ways of writing things):

```
let readMap (path:string) =
    let lines = File.ReadAllLines path
    let [|x; y; n|] = lines.[0].Split() |> Array.map int
    let data = 
        [| 
            for l in lines |> Seq.skip 1 do
                if not (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(l)) then
                    yield l.Split()
        |]
    x,y,n,data
```

I also removed the call to `Array.toSeq`, because F# allows you to use array in a place where seq is expected without an explicit conversion (seq is actually `IEnumerable` and array implements it).

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
val items : string list
items
|> List.filter (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not)
```

?